# Как делать перенаправление с site.ru/ на site.ru/ru/

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Как делать перенаправление с site.ru/ на site.ru/ru/

Пробовал так:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /ru/ [L]
```

Выдает ошибку 500

А так:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Ругается что переадресацию много раз делаю

Answer (score 1):

чтоб не было циклической переадресации, можно проверять, что url не начинается с /ru/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*) http://site.ru/ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```